# What's causing multiple meta tags on my wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I honestly have no idea when or why it started, but I'm getting multiple meta tags generated for my WordPress posts.

[My site.](http://crtive.com)

I'm running **BlackMag** on the latest version of WP.

My Plugins are:

Advertising Manager

Akismet

BackWPup

Better RSS Widget

Contact Form 7

Display Authors Widget

Dynamic Widgets

Easy Social Share Buttons for WordPress

Exclude Pages from Navigation

Featured Image In Rss Feed

Go Daddy Quick Setup

Google Analytics

Google Tag Manager for Wordpress

Insert Headers and Footers

iThemes Security

Jetpack by WordPress.com

P3 (Plugin Performance Profiler)

Pretty Link Lite

Restrict Widgets

Sexy Author Bio

SumoMe

TinyMCE Advanced

Ultimate Tag Cloud Widget

User Role Editor

W3 Total Cache

WP-Optimize

WP Mobile Detect

WP Post Template

WP Smush

WP User Avatar

Yoast SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the double analytics code - did you, by any chance, inserted it as pure code (hardcoded or with analytics plugin), and then - once again, with Google Tag Manager?

I don't see any doubled meta tags, anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

Yost SEO is most likely putting your excerpt in your meta description